# How to delete a non-empty folder in a zip file using Ruby gem 'zip' or 'rubyzip'?

Tags: ruby, zip

I tried to remove a non-empty folder in a zip file.
I am using ruby 1.8.7 in Ubuntu 10.10. I tried `rubyzip` gem and `zip` gem

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
Zip::ZipFile.open('apkfile.apk') { |zfile| zfile.dir.delete('META-INF') }
```

it reported following error

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Now I could only delete every entry in the directory and the directory would be deleted finally after last file in the directory being deleted.

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
Zip::ZipFile.open('apkfile.apk') do |zfile|
    zfile.file.delete("META-INF/foo1.bar") 
    zfile.file.delete("META-INF/foo2.bar")
    zfile.file.delete("META-INF/foo3.bar")
end
```

Is it possible to use `FileUtils.rm_rf` method in fileutils gem in the zip file?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
Zip::ZipFile.open('foo.zip') { |zfile| zfile.remove('bar') }
```

http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html#M000150

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I also tried this. The same error prompted.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Excuse the stupid question, but are you sure there's a directory named `bar` inside your zip?

Answer (score 0):

I was slightly aghast to find that rubyzip would not do this, confounded by the fact that the more promising zipruby also has no obvious way of removing a file at all.

On trying to implement my own recursive delete it seems there is something seriously broken in the implementation of rubyzip; internally it stores an `@entries` object in which other code, most obviously `Zip::ZipFileSystem::ZipFsDir`, expects to find `:directory` type nodes, but there are none there so it throws the not found exception. I will try and get round to posting a bug report.

Anyway the following hack will allow you to delete a directory from a zip file using rubyzip. Note that by emptying a directory this way it vanishes, if you just wanted to empty it you might need to use `ZipFsDir` `mkdir` to add it back.

```
class Zip::ZipFile
  def rm_rf(dir)
    dir_entries = self.entries.select { |e| Regexp.new("^#{File.join(dir, '/')}.*") === e.name }
    dir_entries.each { |e| self.remove(e) }
    dir_entries
  end
end
```

Then use:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(path) do |a|
  a.rm_rf('directory-name')
end
```

to remove a directory.